# Custom pipe returns an error. ::TypeScript & Angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, angular, typescript

I've implemented a new pipe into my code recently. Everything seems to be fine, but while compiling the app, I'm receiving an error. Here's the parts of the app:

**`app.component.ts` file:**

```
import {SortPipe} from "./sort.pipe";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  pipes: [ SortPipe ]
})
```

**`sort.pipe.ts` file:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private ts: number;

  transform(array: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a.ts < b.ts) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.ts > b.ts) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

**`app.component.html` file:**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let elem of (_values | sort)">
```

**Error which I'm receiving:**

> ERROR in [default] C:\Users\app.component.ts:11:2
>   Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: any; styles: any[]; pipes: typeof SortPipe[]; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Component'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.

I don't really know why this happens, because I've read some informations on SO about this problem and the solution in most cases was just to include the pipe name in the `app.module.ts`. My module looks like (minified version):

```
import { SortPipe } from './sort.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     SortPipe
  ] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If anybody got any ideas how to fix it or any hints, please share it.

Comment: Missing comma after `templateUrl: './app.component.html'`?

Comment: @rinukkusu Just a small typo while rewriting code onto SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the newer versions of angular-cli **you don't have to declare pipes inside the component or even import it directly to the component**. Just declare your pipe inside the `.module` file:

```
import { SortPipe } from 'sort.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SortPipe
})
```

If you want to sort your array of objects by specified property, use following code:

`sort.pipe.ts`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private name: any;

  transform(array: any, args: any): any {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
      a.property - b.property     //in your case: a.name - b.name  
    );
    return array;
  }
}
```

**Important:** Remember, the property which you want to sort the array by has to be type of `number` or `any`. If the property is a string, you have to declare the type as `any`.

The last step is connecting your pipe with `*ngFor` loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let elem of _values | sort">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you no need to make module for pipe, you can directly inject in your `app.module.ts` like this:

```
import {SortPipe} from "YOURPATH/sort.pipe";
```

then inject it in `declarations` like this:

```
 declarations: [..., SortPipe]
```

and now use it anywhere in your application.

Working `pipe` code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sort'
})

export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {    
        value.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (a.ts > b.ts) ? 1 : ((b.ts > a.ts) ? -1 : 0); });

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing using this?

Comment: The issue is that the error still appears. Same error.

Comment: Have you removed `import {SortPipe} from "./sort.pipe";`  and `pipes: [ SortPipe ]` from `component`? Using same what I mention above then no need to inject in component.

Comment: The error is gone but the sorting function doesnt work

Comment: Can you post `array` what **value** you want to sort?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130619/discussion-between-avnesh-shakya-and-h-doe).

Comment: The array of objects: 
[{ 
"name": "t10", 
"ts": 1476778297100, 
"value": "32.339264", 
"xid": "DP_049908" 
}, { 
"name": "t17", 
"ts": 1476778341100, 
"value": "true", 
"xid": "DP_693259" 
}, { 
"name": "t16", 
"ts": 1476778341100, 
"value": "true", 
"xid": "DP_891890" 
}];

Comment: I updated my answer with working `pipe` code. Hope it will work for you also.