# Why custom pipe is giving Error: Property 'transform' in type 'EllipsisPipe' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'SlicePipe'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I've created a custom pipe with the help of someone else's answer on stackoverflow. If `article.title` is larger than 55 characters then it should get trimmed after 55 characters and three dots should be there like a tail. For e.g:

1. How to make a cake
2. How to make cold c...
3. Making curry at ho...
4. Tasty Spanish eggs

Notice point 2 and 3 how extra characters are trimmed and replaced with 3 dots.

Here's the code:

**ellipses.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { SlicePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ellipsis'
})
export class EllipsisPipe extends SlicePipe {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  transform(value: string, maxLength: number): any {
    const suffix = value && value.length > maxLength ? "..." : "";
    return super.transform(value, 0, maxLength) + suffix;
  }
}
```

**Note:** I tried `...implements PipeTransform` also.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    EllipsisPipe // <-------------------- included in app module
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{article.title | ellipsis:55}}</h5>
```

Please correct my mistake. This question didn't help:
[Custom pipe returns an error. ::TypeScript & Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145287/custom-pipe-returns-an-error-typescript-angular2).

PS: Complete error is:

> ERROR in src/app/pipes/ellipsis.pipe.ts(11,3): error TS2416: Property
>   'transform' in type 'EllipsisPipe' is not assignable to the same
>   property in base type 'SlicePipe'.   Type '(value: string, maxLength:
>   number) => any' is not assignable to type '{ (value: readonly T[],
>   start: number, end?: number): T[]; (value: string, start: number,
>   end?: number): string; (value: null, start: number, end?: number):
>   null; (value: undefined, start: number, end?: number): undefined; }'.
>       Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
>         Type 'readonly any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

One strange thing is that It is working on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8yp86) but giving the above error on localhost:4200.

Comment: I guess that's because the type of parameter value in transform method should be string[]

Comment: i just added a stackblitz. There it is working. Strange thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either one of these implementations:

1. In the HTML, use this:

   ```
   {{item | slice:0:15}} {{ item.length > 15 ? "...": "" }}
   ```
2. Change the pipe code to this:

   ```
   export class EllipsisPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, maxLength: number): any {
   const suffix = value && value.length > maxLength ? "..." : "";
   return new SlicePipe().transform(value, 0, maxLength) + suffix;
   }}
   ```

In your code, the `transform` function was clashing with the existing functions in the parent class aka `SlicingPipe`. Simply, implementing the `PipeTransform` interface and calling the appropriate function in `SlicePipe` can do the job.

`PipeTransform` is also actually optional. (https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

> The PipeTransform interface The transform method is essential to a
>   pipe. The PipeTransform interface defines that method and guides both
>   tooling and the compiler. Technically, it's optional; Angular looks
>   for and executes the transform method regardless.

Please see the other answers which have links to nice articles.

Comment: I will prefer the second approach. Error has gone now and it is working also. Now I'll run unit tests. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: Please explain this answer a little bit more.

Comment: I have this problem after upgrading from ng 10 to ng 11. Having the return type changed to any does the trick, but not nice. Not sure this is a bug in NG 11 or TS 4.0.5?

Answer (score 5):

You can also (in addition to already proposed solutions) try to use type script function overloading for the base class, actually you can try to add a list of method signatures that satisfy both current class and [base class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.5/packages/common/src/pipes/slice_pipe.ts#L64)

```
transform(value: string, start: number, end?: number): string;
transform(value: null, start: number, end?: number): null;
transform(value: string, maxLength: number): any {
  const suffix = value && value.length > maxLength ? '...' : '';
  return super.transform(value, 0, maxLength) + suffix;
}
```

Some resources:

- [Demystifying Function Overloading in TypeScript](https://engineering.datorama.com/demystifying-function-overloading-in-typescript-eb9f8ca6b87d)
- [Typescript child class function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025364/typescript-child-class-function-overloading)

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kj9rtgcustompipe-mfv6es

Comment: Awesome ! I was looking for this .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Error is due to overriding of method `transform` from `SlicePipe`  in your `EllipsisPipe`.

`Transform` in `Slice pipe` has method signatures as

- `<T>(value: readonly T[], start: number, end?: number): T[];`
- `(value: string, start: number, end?: number): string;`
- `(value: null,start: number, end?: number): null;`
- `(value: undefined, start: number, end?: number): undefined;`

But your signature is

```
transform(value: string, maxLength: number): any
```

Try implementing `transform` method of  `PipeTransform`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SlicePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ellipsis'
})
export class EllipsisPipe extends SlicePipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value, maxLength): any {
    const suffix = value && value.length > maxLength ? "..." : "";
    return super.transform(value, 0, maxLength) + suffix;
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kj9rtgcustompipe

Comment: I'm accepting Nikhil's answer as it is short and crisp. And also it is easy to write unit test cases for the same. Other answers are equally useful and correct. Thanks everyone. :-)